# Navbar Dropdown with overflow hidden

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm creating a Bootstrap Navbar using the `react-bootstrap` library that is meant to be horizontally scrollable when it would otherwise overflow off the page.

The horizontal scroll I've created requires that the Navbar have `overflow-x: hidden` applied to it. This has caused the dropdowns to become partially hidden behind it.

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Is there a way to maintain the scrolling functionality and display these dropdowns correctly? Also does anyone know how I can prevent the vertical scrolling that the dropdown is causing when it's open?

Stackblitz Website View: https://react-ts-jtybfz.stackblitz.io/

Stackblitz Editor View: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-jtybfz?file=index.tsx,NavBar.tsx,index.html

index.ts:

```js
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(
  document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement
);

root.render(<NavBar />);
```

`NavBar` Component:

```js
export const NavBar = () => {
  const scrollRef: MutableRefObject<HTMLElement | null> = useRef(null);
  const onWheel = (e: WheelEvent) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    const container = scrollRef.current;
    const scrollPos = container.scrollLeft;

    container.scrollTo({
      top: 0,
      left: scrollPos + e.deltaY,
    });
  };

  const spam = Array(35).fill(<NavLink to="">Example</NavLink>);

  return (
    <Navbar bg="light" ref={scrollRef} onWheel={onWheel}>
      <Container>
        <Nav className="me-auto">
          <NavDropdown title="Dropdown" id="basic-nav-dropdown">
            <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.1">Action</NavDropdown.Item>
            <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.2">
              Another action
            </NavDropdown.Item>
            <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.3">Something</NavDropdown.Item>
            <NavDropdown.Divider />
            <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.4">
              Separated link
            </NavDropdown.Item>
          </NavDropdown>
          {spam}
        </Nav>
      </Container>
    </Navbar>
  );
};
```

Required CSS:

```css
nav.navbar {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: visible;
}
```

Edit: Here is a gif showing the issue. You can scroll just fine until you click the dropdown, and then the dropdown is not visible and the scrolling also scrolls vertically. I want this dropdown to not affect the parents height and be visible while maintaining the scrolling functionality.

[image]

Comment: Could it be that you posted the wrong pictures? I don't see a scroll bar in them at all.

Comment: @GabeRAMturn there isn't a scrollbar on purpose, the `overflow-x: hidden` hides all the stuff that you can scroll to and the `NavBar` class handles the scrolling. Having no scrollbar is a part of the client's requirements for some reason...

Comment: I don't understand your requirement clearly but is it something that you are looking for: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-2uyeme?file=index.tsx,NavBar.tsx,index.html ?

Comment: @micronyks I need to be able to horizontally scroll the navbar as well but otherwise yeah

Comment: @MichaelGoodwin so you want to be able to scroll while the scroll bar is invisible/hidden ?

Comment: @Aymendps Yes. The client doesn't want a visible scrollbar but when scrolling with your mouse wheel the navbar should move left to right. My example displays this functionality.

The issue comes with the dropdown being hidden

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try doing it via the ref. Just changing the overflow prop

```
<NavDropdown
        onClick={() => {
         
          getComputedStyle(scrollRef.current).overflowX === 'hidden'
            ? (scrollRef.current.style.overflowX = 'visible')
            : (scrollRef.current.style.overflowX = 'hidden');
        }}
        title="Dropdown"
        id="basic-nav-dropdown"
      >
```

Comment: StackBlitz : https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-wmxpla?file=index.tsx,NavBar.tsx,index.html

Comment: This works for the most part but it seems like it can become desynced, I'm going to award you the points anyway since you got the closest to what I need. I think I can probably work this into my solution somehow.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is to remove `overflow-x: hidden;`, set `width: max-content;`, and then move the navbar through style.left property:

```
container.scrollTo({
  top: 0,
  left: scrollPos + e.deltaY,
});
```

becomes:

```
container.style.left =
  Math.min(
    0,
    Math.max(
      +window.getComputedStyle(document.body).width.slice(0, -2) -
        +container.scrollWidth,
      +container.style.left.slice(0, -2) - e.deltaY
    )
  ) + 'px';
```

here's it in action: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-3us1sz?file=index.tsx,NavBar.tsx,index.html

Comment: The scrolling doesn't seem to work consistently